# Change sprite of player when touching a button Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the sprite of the players in a scene.
I have a script that manages which script is activated when you switch from a player to another.
I'd like to add the feature that when switching the inactive player goes black & white trought a sprite and the active player mantain the colored sprite.
Can anyone help, cause is not changing sprite on the player first and player second GameObject?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class switchCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Psyco1;
    public GameObject Psyco2;
    public PlayerControllerPsyco1 script1;
    public PlayerControllerPsyco2 script2;
    public Sprite sprite1; // Psyco1 color
    public Sprite sprite2; // Psyco2 decolorized
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRendererPsyco1; 
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRendererPsyco2; 

    void  Start (){
        script1 = Psyco1.GetComponent<PlayerControllerPsyco1>();
        script2 = Psyco2.GetComponent<PlayerControllerPsyco2>();
        script1.enabled = true;
        script2.enabled = false;
        spriteRendererPsyco1 = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRendererPsyco2 = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite == null) // if the sprite on spriteRenderer is null then
            spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite1; // set the sprite to Psyco1 Color
    }

    void  Update (){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("switch1")){
            script1.enabled = !script1.enabled;
            script2.enabled = !script2.enabled;
            //spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite2;
            DesaturizePsyco (); // call method to change Psyco sprite
        }
    }

    public void changeCharacterBtn() {
        if (script1.enabled = !script1.enabled) // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
        {
            GameObject.Find ("PlayerFirst").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprite2;
        }
        //script1.enabled = !script1.enabled;
        if (script2.enabled = !script2.enabled;) // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
        {
            GameObject.Find ("PlayerSecond").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprite1;
        }
        //script2.enabled = !script2.enabled;
        DesaturizePsyco ();

    }

    void DesaturizePsyco ()
    {
        if (spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite == sprite1) // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
        {
            GameObject.Find ("PlayerFirst").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = sprite2;
        }
        else
        {
            spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite1; // otherwise change it back to sprite1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so, if you solved it using a posted answer please consider selecting it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

First try to always post a minimal stripped script: here the `changeCharacterBtn()` method wasn't useful (I suggested an edit for your post already). Also there was a typo in it at `if (script2.enabled = !script2.enabled;)`. Also I guess your code would throw errors when played: did you check the *Console*?

Concerning your script, here are the errors I see:

- `spriteRendererPsyco1 = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();` instead of `spriteRendererPsyco1 = Psyco1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();` (same for Psyco2)
- The `script1`, `script2`, `spriteRendererPsyco1` and `spriteRendererPsyco2` should be set to private since you reference them in `Start()` (no need for them to appear on Inspector)

So here is a corrected version of your script:

```
public class switchCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Psyco1;
    public GameObject Psyco2;
    private PlayerControllerPsyco1 script1;
    private PlayerControllerPsyco1 script2;
    public Sprite sprite1; // Psyco1 color
    public Sprite sprite2; // Psyco2 decolorized
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRendererPsyco1;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRendererPsyco2;

    void Start()
    {
        script1 = Psyco1.GetComponent<PlayerControllerPsyco1>();
        script2 = Psyco2.GetComponent<PlayerControllerPsyco1>();
        script1.enabled = true;
        script2.enabled = false;
        spriteRendererPsyco1 = Psyco1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRendererPsyco2 = Psyco2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if(spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite == null) // if the sprite on spriteRenderer is null then
            spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite1; // set the sprite to Psyco1 Color
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("switch1"))
        {
            script1.enabled = !script1.enabled;
            script2.enabled = !script2.enabled;
            //spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite2;
            DesaturizePsyco(); // call method to change Psyco sprite
        }
    }

    void DesaturizePsyco()
    {
        if(spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite == sprite1) // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
        {
            GameObject.Find("PlayerFirst").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite2;
        }
        else
        {
            spriteRendererPsyco1.sprite = sprite1; // otherwise change it back to sprite1
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, here are few things about general programming advises:

- Consider using capital letters to start class names (this is a general convention in C#)
- Using *Sprites* comparison to determine which player is currently on is maybe not the most robust way to proceed (maybe consider using a `bool` variable instead)
- Always try to keep your code as clean as possible (no double-spaces, keeping the same naming convention using capital letters or not: `Psyco1` but `script1`, ...)

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: This not changed the state of the script, problem still remaining.

Comment: Well I tried the script as I posted it with 2 _GameObjects_ each holding a _SpriteRenderer_ component (and one being called _PlayerFirst_). and it worked perfectly. Are your sure all of the fields are assigned in the Inspector? Is there any error displayed in the Console?

Comment: Yes check errors. And try debugging so you will find what part of the code is the one broken